# Erlang: Cannot start slave - {error,timeout}

Tags: erlang, slave, tsung

I'm currently trying to set up a distributed Tsung load testing
environment which uses the Erlang slave functionality, however I have
been unsuccessful in getting the controller node to start a slave
node. E.g.

```
(musicglue@load1)1> net:ping(musicglue@load2).
pong
(musicglue@load1)2> slave:start(load2,musicglue,"-setcookie tom").
{error,timeout}
```

### BACKGROUND

My env:

Controller - hostname: load1, user: musicglue, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS,
Erlang R15B01 compiled from source
Slave - hostname: load2, user: musicglue, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Erlang
R15B01 complied from source
Firewall disabled
SELinux not installed

Things that are working:

- I can SSH from load1 onto load2 and vice versa
- I can start an erl sessions on load1 and load2
- I can start an erl session on load2 from load1; ssh load2 erl
- I can successfully ping load2 from load1 from an erl session using
  the same cookie on both nodes.

Ping output:

```
musicglue@load1:~$ erl -rsh ssh -sname musicglue -setcookie tom
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:
0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(musicglue@load1)1> net:ping(musicglue@load2).
pong
```

### THE ISSUE

My problem occurs when attempting to start a slave session from load1
on load2:

```
musicglue@load1:~$ erl -rsh ssh -sname musicglue -setcookie tom
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:
0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(musicglue@load1)1> net:ping(musicglue@load2).
pong
(musicglue@load1)2> slave:start(load2,musicglue,"-setcookie
tom").
{error,timeout}
```

Here is the output I get from epmd when I run the slave:start command:

```
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: Non-local peer connected
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: opening connection on file descriptor
4
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: got 12 bytes
***** 00000000  00 0a 7a 6d 75 73 69 63 67 6c 75 65
|..zmusicglue|
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: ** got PORT2_REQ
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: got 2 bytes
***** 00000000  77 01                                             |w.|
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: ** sent PORT2_RESP (error) for
"musicglue"
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: closing connection on file descriptor
4
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: Local peer connected
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: opening connection on file descriptor
4
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: got 24 bytes
***** 00000000  00 16 78 ca d6 4d 00 00  05 00 05 00 09 6d 75 73
|..x..M.......mus|
***** 00000010  69 63 67 6c 75 65 00 00                           |
icglue..|
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: ** got ALIVE2_REQ
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: registering 'musicglue:1', port 51926
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: type 77 proto 0 highvsn 5 lowvsn 5
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: got 4 bytes
***** 00000000  79 00 00 01                                       |
y...|
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: ** sent ALIVE2_RESP for "musicglue"
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: unregistering 'musicglue:1', port
51926
epmd: Thu May 24 10:01:57 2012: closing connection on file descriptor
4
```

Any help or suggestions anyone has would be much appreciated,

Many thanks

### EDIT

I should also mention that I can see the ssh connection being successfully acknowledged by load2 but then immediately disconnecting:

```
May 30 13:49:27 load2 sshd[16169]: Accepted publickey for musicglue from 173.45.236.182 port 51843 ssh2
May 30 13:49:27 load2 sshd[16171]: Received disconnect from 173.45.236.182: 11: disconnected by user
```

In response to below comments I have also tried to start the slave using different node names for the slave:

```
musicglue@load1:~$ erl -rsh ssh -sname musicglue -setcookie tom
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(musicglue@load1)1> slave:start(load2,bar,"-setcookie tom").
{error,timeout}
```

and for the controller:

```
musicglue@load1:~$ erl -rsh ssh -sname foo -setcookie tom
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(foo@load1)1> slave:start(load2,musicglue,"-setcookie tom").
{error,timeout}
```

and for both:

```
musicglue@load1:~$ erl -rsh ssh -sname foo -setcookie tom
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(foo@load1)1> slave:start(load2,bar,"-setcookie tom").
{error,timeout}
```

But to no avail

### SOLUTION

Turns out that my problem was that my slave was unable to SSH onto the controller and therefore could not respond to any commands.

After fixing this port of communication between the two nodes everyone worked perfectly.

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to start a new slave on `load2` with the same name, `musicglue`, as an existing node. You name names must be unique on a machine.

Comment: Thanks @rvirding. I have tried a combination of different node names (see edited post) but still no luck. Have I misinterpreted your comment?

Comment: @rvirding thought you might be interested to know that after fixing my problem (described above), I _was_ able to use the same name on both controller and slave

Comment: How exactly you fixed port of communication, PLEASE HELP

Comment: @TomMaguire how did you fix the communication problem ?

Answer (score 3):

An alternate answer for those who find this question via Google.  If you're trying to start a service on a separate machine then your controller node name must resolve.

For example, I was having timeouts with:

```
> node().
someName@host.domain.com
> slave:start('192.168.122.196',bar,"-setcookie cookie").
{error,timeout}
```

By starting my erlang instance with an explicit domain name:

```
erl -name someName@192.168.1.5 -setcookie cookie
> slave:start('192.168.122.196',bar,"-setcookie cookie").
```

This command now succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

Try logging what goes on through SSH by creating a shell script like this somewhere in your `PATH`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$0" "$@" > /tmp/my-ssh.log
ssh -v "$@"  2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/my-ssh.log
```

Call it `my-ssh`, start Erlang with `erl -rsh my-ssh`, and check what goes into `/tmp/my-ssh.log`. That should shed some light on the problem...

Comment: Thanks @legoscia, that's a very useful little script. I shall be using that in future for sure!