# Erlang: {error,timeout} when starting the 14th slave on the same machine

Tags: erlang

I am experiencing the following behaviour when starting slaves:

```
aura:/home/xtomast1>$ erl -rsh ssh -sname root_worker
Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [smp:64:64] [rq:64] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
(root_worker@aura)1> slave:start(localhost, 1).
{ok,'1@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)2> slave:start(localhost, 2).
{ok,'2@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)3> slave:start(localhost, 3).
{ok,'3@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)4> slave:start(localhost, 4).
{ok,'4@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)5> slave:start(localhost, 5).
{ok,'5@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)6> slave:start(localhost, 6).
{ok,'6@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)7> slave:start(localhost, 7).
{ok,'7@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)8> slave:start(localhost, 8).
{ok,'8@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)9> slave:start(localhost, 9).
{ok,'9@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)10> slave:start(localhost, 10).
{ok,'10@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)11> slave:start(localhost, 11).
{ok,'11@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)12> slave:start(localhost, 12).
{ok,'12@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)13> slave:start(localhost, 13).
{ok,'13@localhost'}
(root_worker@aura)14> slave:start(localhost, 14).
{error,timeout}
```

I suspected that it is an ssh-related problem, so I attempted troubleshooting using a method provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10832210/2199413), but [the obtained log](http://pastebin.com/RzkRx3J5) shows that the 14th authentication attempt succeeds just as the first 13 did.

<sup>Now I have no idea what to try next. I know next to nothing about Erlang and this problem, which I have presented above in an interactive shell session, is also manifesting itself when running a certain Erlang program which I really need to work - so any help would be greatly appreciated.</sup>

Comment: Are there limits set on the user running the program, that stops the user from creating that many resources?

Comment: Well, there may be (it's an university server), but I don't know about any. I am able to run tasks that fully utilize 40 or more CPU cores and allocate 100 GB or more of memory. (Or is that not what you had in mind?) If no other suggestion surfaces, I will try to ask the admins.

Comment: That's the sort of thing I had in mind, yes - such as limits on the number of open files, etc. It'd probably be interesting to see the system logs on that server.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with R15B01 (the oldest Erlang I have available): I can start more than 14 slaves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is connected to `max user processes` limit, each slave node seems to be using 3 Operating-System processes in my test.  If you have a low limit on user processes or have started too many already this might lead to a error like yours.

You did not specify what operating system you are trying this on, but I suppose it is Unix alike.

To see your current limits settings type

```
ulimit -a
```

at the shell.

Also it might be interesting to list all your processes.  Since your Erlang is reporting 64 Smp-Cores it will want to start 64 scheduler threads.  I can't see this on my OS but maybe there is even a limit on threads you may start.  If every slave also starts 64 threads you have quite a bunch of then running.

Comment: Your suspicion was correct. (Also, thank you for listing the exact command, I didn't know about it before.) Each slave was starting 64 threads and they counted towards the `max user processes` limit.